# How to merge 2 dataframes using groupby function having 2 different logics within a single loop in large dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of climate data at `15 minutes interval` of a large number of stations from which I have to extract the **rainfall data** specifically at `TIME (UTC) 03:00:00` for each date
and have to **average the soil moisture at each depth for whole day** i.e `(have to average the 96 values on a specific date)` in case of soil moisture, so basically have to extract single value of these `5 climate varibales` on `each day` for `each station`.

the dataset columns are like

```
        DISTRICT    STATION             DATE    TIME (UTC)  RAINFALL CUMULATIVE SINCE 03 UTC (mm)  SOIL MOIS 10 cm (m3/m3)  SOIL MOIS 30 cm (m3/m3) SOIL MOIS 70cm (m3/m3)  SOIL MOIS 100cm (m3/m3) STATE   DATE_TIME
0      NORTH_GOA    NORTH GOA_KVK   2021-09-02  00:00:00    4.0                                    32.0                     29.0                    11.0                    6.0                     GOA     2021-09-02 00:00:00
1      NORTH_GOA    NORTH GOA_KVK   2021-09-02  00:15:00    4.0                                    32.0                     29.0                    11.0                    6.0                     GOA     2021-09-02 00:15:00
2      NORTH_GOA    NORTH GOA_KVK   2021-09-02  00:30:00    4.0                                    32.0                     29.0                    11.0                    6.0                     GOA     2021-09-02 00:30:00
3      NORTH_GOA    NORTH GOA_KVK   2021-09-02  00:45:00    4.0                                    32.0                     29.0                    11.0                    6.0                     GOA     2021-09-02 00:45:00
4      NORTH_GOA    NORTH GOA_KVK   2021-09-02  01:00:00    4.0                                    32.0                     29.0                    11.0                    6.0                     GOA     2021-09-02 01:00:00
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
743420  PALAKKAD    PATTAMBI_KVK    2021-09-02  22:45:00    0.0                                    20.0                     18.0                    28.0                    42.0                   KERALA   2021-09-02 22:45:00
743421  PALAKKAD    PATTAMBI_KVK    2021-09-02  23:00:00    0.0                                    20.0                     18.0                    28.0                    42.0                   KERALA   2021-09-02 23:00:00
743422  PALAKKAD    PATTAMBI_KVK    2021-09-02  23:15:00    0.0                                    20.0                     18.0                    28.0                    42.0                   KERALA   2021-09-02 23:15:00
743423  PALAKKAD    PATTAMBI_KVK    2021-09-02  23:30:00    0.0                                    20.0                     18.0                    28.0                    42.0                   KERALA   2021-09-02 23:30:00
743424  PALAKKAD    PATTAMBI_KVK    2021-09-02  23:45:00    0.0                                    20.0                     18.0                    28.0                    42.0                   KERALA   2021-09-02 23:45:00

743425 rows × 11 columns
```

Whole dataset had a lot of columns so just mentioning here which are required.

```
S NO.                                     object
DISTRICT                                  object
STATION                                   object
 DATE                                     object
TIME (UTC)                                object
RAINFALL CUMULATIVE SINCE 03 UTC (mm)    float64
TEMPERATURE (C)                          float64
TEMP MAX MIN (C)                         float64
RH(%)                                    float64
RH MAX MIN (%)                           float64
WIND DIR 10m (Deg)                        object
WIND SPEED 10m (Kt)                       object
WIND SPEED MAX / GUST 10m (Kt)            object
WIND DIR 3m (Deg)                         object
WIND SPEED 3m (Kt)                        object
WIND SPEED MAX / GUST 3m (Kt)             object
SLP (hPa)                                float64
MSLP (hPa/gpm)                           float64
SUNSHINE (HH.MM)                         float64
SOIL TEMP 10cm (C)                       float64
SOIL MOIS 10 cm (m3/m3)                  float64
SOIL TEMP 30 cm (C)                      float64
SOIL MOIS 30 cm (m3/m3)                  float64
SOIL TEMP 70 cm (C)                      float64
SOIL MOIS 70cm (m3/m3)                   float64
SOIL TEMP 100 cm (C)                     float64
SOIL MOIS 100cm (m3/m3)                  float64
 GLOBAL RADIATION (v/m2)                 float64
PAR (micro-mole/m2s)                     float64
BATTERY (Volts)                          float64
GPS                                       object
Unnamed: 31                              float64
STATE                                     object
dtype: object
```

Extracting `Rainfall` and `Soil moisture` separately by groupby function in pandas was quite easy which I did as

`For Rainfall`

```
########## extract rainfall at 3 UTC ######################################################
Selected_UTC = "03:00:00"

UTC_df = all_csv_dataframe.loc[(all_csv_dataframe['TIME (UTC)'] == Selected_UTC)].reset_index()

STATION_df = UTC_df.groupby('STATION')
for d in STATION_df:
    station = d[0]
    station_data = d[1][['index', 'DISTRICT', 'STATION', 'STATE', ' DATE ','RAINFALL CUMULATIVE SINCE 03 UTC (mm)']]
    
    state_name = station_data["STATE"].iloc[0]
    district_name = station_data["DISTRICT"].iloc[0]
    
    sorted_station_rf_data_df = station_data.sort_values(by=[' DATE '], ascending=[True])
```

the output for each station is ***(Output / dataframe 1)***

```
        index   DISTRICT    STATION     STATE       DATE        RAINFALL CUMULATIVE SINCE 03 UTC (mm)
2126    201811  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-07-01  37.5
2127    201907  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-07-02  45.0
2128    202002  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-07-03  1.0
2129    202098  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-07-04  0.0
2130    202194  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-07-05  0.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
1127    107531  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-09-11  0.0
1128    107627  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-09-12  0.0
1129    107722  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-09-13  0.0
1130    107817  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-09-14  2.0
1131    107912  KHAMMAM     WYRA_KVK    TELANGANA   2021-09-15  0.0
74 rows × 6 columns
```

`For Soil Moisture`

```
STATION_df = all_csv_dataframe.groupby('STATION')
for d in STATION_df:
    station = d[0]
    station_data = d[1]
    state_name = station_data["STATE"].iloc[0]
    district_name = station_data["DISTRICT"].iloc[0]

    average_soil_moisture_df = station_data.groupby(' DATE ')[['SOIL MOIS 10 cm (m3/m3)','SOIL MOIS 30 cm (m3/m3)','SOIL MOIS 70cm (m3/m3)','SOIL MOIS 100cm (m3/m3)']].mean().reset_index()
    
    average_soil_moisture_df.set_index([' DATE '], inplace=True)
    
    sorted_station_data_sm_df = average_soil_moisture_df.sort_values(by=[' DATE '], ascending=[True])
```

the output for each station is ***(Output / dataframe 2)***

```
DATE       SOIL MOIS 10 cm (m3/m3)  SOIL MOIS 30 cm (m3/m3) SOIL MOIS 70cm (m3/m3)  SOIL MOIS 100cm (m3/m3)
                
2021-07-01  32.791667               49.520833               32.104167               35.010417
2021-07-02  33.357895               51.094737               36.347368               40.221053
2021-07-03  29.958333               49.093750               34.781250               39.458333
2021-07-04  29.000000               48.718750               34.000000               39.000000
2021-07-05  28.770833               48.000000               34.000000               39.000000
... ... ... ... ...
2021-09-11  26.000000               47.000000               34.000000               41.000000
2021-09-12  26.000000               47.000000               34.000000               40.684211
2021-09-13  25.536842               46.178947               34.000000               41.000000
2021-09-14  25.000000               46.000000               34.000000               40.715789
2021-09-15  25.000000               46.000000               34.000000               40.000000
74 rows × 4 columns
```

How to iterate them in a single loop so that ***Output / dataframe 1*** and ***Output / dataframe 2*** merge together `over date` to form a single dataframe for `each station`.

I tried this way but could not get the desired output

```
STATION_df = all_csv_dataframe.groupby(by=['STATION'])

########## extract rainfall at 3 UTC ######################################################
Selected_UTC = "03:00:00"

for d in STATION_df:
    station = d[0]
    station_data = d[1]
    state_name = station_data["STATE"].iloc[0]
    district_name = station_data["DISTRICT"].iloc[0]
    
    average_soil_moisture_df = station_data.groupby(' DATE ')[['SOIL MOIS 10 cm (m3/m3)','SOIL MOIS 30 cm (m3/m3)','SOIL MOIS 70cm (m3/m3)','SOIL MOIS 100cm (m3/m3)']].mean().reset_index()

    average_soil_moisture_df.set_index([' DATE '], inplace=True)

    sorted_station_data_sm_df = average_soil_moisture_df.sort_values(by=[' DATE '], ascending=[True])

    UTC_df = STATION_df.apply(lambda g: g[g['TIME (UTC)'] == Selected_UTC])
    UTC_df.set_index(['STATION'], inplace=True)

    STATION_rf_df = UTC_df.groupby('STATION')
    for d in STATION_rf_df:
        station = d[0]
        station_data = d[1][['DISTRICT', 'STATE', ' DATE ','RAINFALL CUMULATIVE SINCE 03 UTC (mm)']]

        state_name = station_data["STATE"].iloc[0]
        district_name = station_data["DISTRICT"].iloc[0]

        sorted_station_rf_data_df = station_data.sort_values(by=[' DATE '], ascending=[True])
    
        merged_Frame = pd.merge(sorted_station_rf_data_df, sorted_station_data_sm_df, on = ' DATE ', how='inner')
        merged_Frame
```

The final output for each station should be like:

```
    DISTRICT    STATE           DATE        RAINFALL CUMULATIVE SINCE 03 UTC (mm)    SOIL MOIS 10 cm (m3/m3)    SOIL MOIS 30 cm (m3/m3)   SOIL MOIS 70cm (m3/m3)     SOIL MOIS 100cm (m3/m3)
0   BALRAMPUR   UTTAR_PRADESH   2021-08-28  4.5                                      50.684211                  52.000000                 52.884211                  52.000000
1   BALRAMPUR   UTTAR_PRADESH   2021-08-29  4.5                                      50.684211                  52.000000                 52.884211                  52.000000
2   BALRAMPUR   UTTAR_PRADESH   2021-08-30  4.5                                      50.684211                  52.000000                 52.884211                  52.000000
3   BALRAMPUR   UTTAR_PRADESH   2021-08-31  4.5                                      50.684211                  52.000000                 52.884211                  52.000000
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
70  BALRAMPUR   UTTAR_PRADESH   2021-09-12  4.5                                      50.684211                  52.000000                 52.884211                  52.000000
71  BALRAMPUR   UTTAR_PRADESH   2021-09-13  4.5                                      50.684211                  52.000000                 52.884211                  52.000000
72  BALRAMPUR   UTTAR_PRADESH   2021-09-14  4.5                                      50.684211                  52.000000                 52.884211                  52.000000
73  BALRAMPUR   UTTAR_PRADESH   2021-09-15  4.5                                      50.684211                  52.000000                 52.884211                  52.000000
74 rows × 8 columns
```

Where, for each station **column RAINFALL CUMULATIVE SINCE 03 UTC** should be having values at `TIME (UTC) 03:00:00` and ** column SOIL MOIS 10 cm (m3/m3)** should be having `average values of each day i.e average of 96 values on a specific date`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using groupby().agg() and directly get one dataset. If you don't need that 'INDEX' variable you can just avoid to pass it

```
df = df.loc[df['TIME (UTC)']=='03:00:00']

df.columns = [i.strip() for i in df.columns]

new_df = df.groupby(['DATE','STATION']).agg({'INDEX':np.unique, 'TIME (UTC)':np.unique, 
                                    'RAINFALL CUMULATIVE SINCE 03 UTC (mm)':np.unique,
                                 'SOIL MOIS 10 cm (m3/m3)':np.mean, 'SOIL MOIS 30 cm (m3/m3)':np.mean, 
                           'SOIL MOIS 70cm (m3/m3)':np.mean,
       'SOIL MOIS 100cm (m3/m3)':np.mean,'STATE':np.unique})
```

Comment: Hiii @Yolao_21, Thanks for your time, but it is producing the ValueError: Must produce aggregated value
However, from this dataset of 743425, I have to extract data in 2 ways, the rainfall of only one time step and soil moisture is average of the day, i.e. it is the average of 96 values on a julian day. this way there is only single value of both parameters for a specific date, hence the dataframe is symmetric. So have to generate a single dataframe of each station. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @AbhilashSinghChauhan! That is because I worked on that snippet of the dataset that you posted and on one date only, which I believe is what causes the issue (because np.unique will return several values and agg() only takes scalar) - for the same reason I removed 'DATE_TIME'. 
Try doing df.groupby(['DATE','STATION']) and remove 'DATE':np.unique from inside agg(), that should return a multi index, with level 1 containing Dates and level 2 containing stations.

Comment: actually, your solution does not give results the way I want

Comment: It is same like 
Selected_UTC = "03:00:00"

UTC_df = all_csv_dataframe.loc[(all_csv_dataframe['TIME (UTC)'] == Selected_UTC)].reset_index()
UTC_df

Comment: the average of soil moisture is of 96 time steps of one day (15 minute each) i.e 4 (15 min) * 24 (hours)

Comment: I have to merge the rainfall data at 03:00:00 UTC with average of soil moisture for same date

Comment: In your case, the soil moisture is also of 03:00:00 UTC, not the average of whole day